# Setting path to custom .irbrc using IRB.conf

Tags: ruby, irb

I want to invoke `irb` dynamically from my Ruby program, but have it not to load the default ~/.irbrc, but a file `./custom_irbrc` instead. I can do it like this:

```
require 'irb'
ENV['IRBRC'] = './custom_irbrc'
IRB.setup(nil)
# My configurations follow here
IRB.conf[...]=...
IRB.start
```

I wonder whether I can set my custom irbrc also via `.conf` instead of polluting the environment. I didn't find a really comprehensive description of the possible conf-settings, but from what I found, I tried as educated guess:

```
IRB.conf[:IRB_RC] = './custom_irbrc'
IRB.conf[:RC] = './custom_irbrc'
```

but neither one seems to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

The desired effect can be achieved, although by using an undocumented feature, and there is no guarantee that it will be available in future Ruby versions too:

```
IRB.conf[:RC_NAME_GENERATOR] = proc { './custom_irbrc' }
```

This has to be done before `IRB.setup` is called.